# Mocking & monitoring Keyboard events with jest in react native

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

Given the following code:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

// ....

componentDidMount() {
  this.keyboardShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
    'keyboardWillShow',
    () => this.setState({ visible: true }),
  );
  this.keyboardHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
    'keyboardWillHide',
    () => this.setState({ visible: false }),
  );
}

// ....

onCancel() {
  const { clearActiveInput } = this.props;
  clearActiveInput();
  Keyboard.dismiss();
}
```

Is there a correct way to mock the imported `Keyboard` component to both verify the listener subscription took place, and also to verify the `dismiss()` event was triggered?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So this problem was way more complex that I could imagine to solve at start.
Since what you want to test here is dismiss() and show() basically for a keyboard right?

Tests were executed with the following lib: @testing-library/react-native

So the events and listeners by documentation for 0.63 and 0.62 is https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#docsNav

```
useEffect(() => {
   Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", _keyboardDidShow);
   Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", _keyboardDidHide);

   // cleanup function
   return () => {
       Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardDidShow", _keyboardDidShow);
       Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardDidHide", _keyboardDidHide);
   };
}, []);

const _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    alert("Keyboard Shown");
};

const _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    alert("Keyboard Hidden");
};
```

To get Jest to call the 2 functions `_keyboardDidShow` and `_keyboardDidHide` you will need to use `Keyboard.emit('keyboardDidShow')`

Example:

```
it('Test Keyboards keyboardDidShow is called', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Container />);
    act(() => {
        Keyboard.emit('keyboardDidShow', {});
    });
    const box = getByTestId('TEST');
    //Do here your expect clauses to check if something changed in your container
});
```

Not fully sure if this will ever help anyone. But that's how I solved this puzzle to figure out how to coverage the _keyboardDidShow and Hide

EDIT:
For version 0.66 > now you need to do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const kds = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", _keyboardDidShow);
  const kdh = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", _keyboardDidHide);

  // cleanup function
  return () => {
    kdh.remove();
    kds.remove();
  };
}, []);

const _keyboardDidShow = () => {
  alert("Keyboard Shown");
};

const _keyboardDidHide = () => {
  alert("Keyboard Hidden");
};
```

Since they changed the way to make it subscription events from now on

And for the tests change the Keyboard.emit to:

```
Keyboard._emitter.emit('keyboardDidShow', {});
Keyboard._emitter.emit('keyboardDidHide', {});
```

And you should have everything you need to make it work in jest :)

Comment: This method works. For those who are confused about the testing syntax used here, the testing is done via [`@testing-library/react-native`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-native-testing-library/intro)

Comment: Keyboard._emitter.emit('keyboardDidHide', {});
This works fine but typescript gives error

Comment: Try: RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit('keyboardDidShow', {});

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? You're literally calling the function you expect to be called within in the test itself. Of course, such a test will pass...

Comment: How do you test if a button was pressed? By firing the press function of the button on selecting the button. Here is the same thing, you test if a keyboard function was called by firing/emit the keyboard action. But im pretty sure there are other ways of doing the same code. There is no perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue with component that subscribed to `Keyboard` events

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {})

        return () => {
            listener.remove()
        }
    })

    return <View>...</View>
}
```

I was able to test `Keyboard.addListener` with following test and also test that `listener.remove` is being called on component unmount

```js
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

const mockListener = {
    remove: jest.fn(),
}
const originalAddListener = Keyboard.addListener
const mockAddListener = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockListener)

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        Keyboard.addListener = mockAddListener
    })
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockAddListener.mockClear()
        mockListener.remove.mockClear()
    })
    afterAll(() => {
        Keyboard.addListener = originalAddListener
    })
    it('should subscribe to KeyboardDidClose event', () => {
        renderer.create(<MyComponent />)
        expect(Keyboard.addListener).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })

    it('should call listener.remove on unmount', () => {
        const component = renderer.create(
            < MyComponent />,
        )
        component.unmount()
        expect(mockListener.remove).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As of React Native 65, jest fails with:
`TypeError: _reactNative.Keyboard.emit is not a function`

I have not yet found a solution for this... I don't think there was any change on Keyboard as per react native docs. Just FYI

EDIT: Fixed with             `DeviceEventEmitter.emit('keyboardWillShow')`

Comment: Try using: Keyboard._emitter.emit('keyboardDidShow', {});

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all of the answers show incorrect testing practices, explicitly calling something on the `Keyboard` object. Rather, you want to run your tests as normal (interacting with UI elements as a normal user would) and then see if these interactions *cause* the keyboard to show! If you write a test explicitly telling the keyboard to open, *of course* your test will pass when you assert if the keyboard was opened!

A better solution is adding an additional listener which is simply a `jest.fn()` function, and then checking if that function was ever called:

```js
// setup mock function
const keyboardDidShowMock = jest.fn();
Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', keyboardDidShowMock);

// press an input, for example
await act(() => {
  fireEvent(
    renderAPI.getByLabelText(`My Input`),
      'press',
    );
  });
});

// wait for and expect that the keyboard did show listener should have been called
waitFor(() => expect(keyboardDidShowMock).toHaveBeenCalled());
```

But note you should *never* have to explicitly call `Keyboard.show()` or `Keyboard.emit()` or *anything* explicitly on the keyboard object! That is a bad test smell.

Comment: On press in an input doesn't call the keyboard. Please try out your answer also on Press should not call any keyboard events but onBlur and also onBlur doesn't call that event on react native.

Comment: If pressing a text input doesn't open the keyboard on your React Native application, you have much larger problems.

Comment: I can guess if what you are rending in your test is not within a screen then yes of course the keyboard won't open. We are using this in our integration tests and it is working fine. I never post answers that I haven't tested myself.

Comment: Related to the keyboard onPress what I meant was: On test environments it won't trigger the keyboard because there is no keyboard to be triggered related to the input, so it wouldn't create a coverage. If you have an automation or a whole implementation it might trigger but depends on the test environment you are working with. With JEST pretty sure it won't call at all the event. Have tested this many times in different projects. If you can provide a example with sandbox of what you are doing :) that might turn the correct answer if all is valid.

Comment: I'm still investigate this. In fact I'm not satisfied with any of the answers

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: Please use the method provided by @Thiago de Oliveira Cruz, which is much cleaner and easier to use.**

I use the method mentioned in [this article](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/testing-global-event-listener-within-a-react-component-b9d661e59953) to "trigger" the `'keyboardDidShow'` and `'keyboardDidHide'` events. Basically, we mock the implementation `keyboard.addListener` and use a map to record the event-to-callback mapping. This way, after a component is mounted, we have access to the callbacks associated with the `'keyboardDidShow'` and `'keyboardDidHide'` events. Then we call the callbacks directly as if the event had been triggered.

This is apparently a workaround, but it works for my use case. Below is a simple example of how to test a component that uses the `'keyboardDidShow'` and `'keyboardDidHide'` events to control whether a piece of text is displayed or not. For a detailed write up about the example, see [here](https://fanchenbao.medium.com/test-hooks-on-keyboarddidshow-in-react-native-functional-component-d0e554303bce).

### Sample component:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Keyboard} from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [showText, setShowText] = React.useState(true);

  // Use keyboard event (https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', _keyboardDidShow);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', _keyboardDidHide);

    // cleanup function
    return () => {
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', _keyboardDidShow);
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', _keyboardDidHide);
    };
  }, []);

  const _keyboardDidShow = () => setShowText(false);
  const _keyboardDidHide = () => setShowText(true);

  if (showText) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Bear, Beets, Battlestar Galactica</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return null;
};

export {MyComponent};
```

### Testing code

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import {MyComponent} from 'mycomponent.js';

describe('Test MyComponent', () => {
  const mockSetShowText = jest.fn();
  const mockUseState = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
  const mockKeyboardListener = jest.spyOn(Keyboard, 'addListener');
  const keyboardCallbackMap = {};

  afterAll(() => {
    mockSetShowText.mockReset();
    mockKeyboardListener.mockRestore();
    mockUseState.mockRestore();
  });

  test('Text shown by default', () => {
    const myComponent = mount(<MyComponent />);
    expect(myComponent.find('Text').first()).toHaveText(
      'Bear, Beets, Battlestar Galactica',
    );
  });

  test('Text not show when showText is false', () => {
    mockUseState.mockReturnValue([false, mockSetShowText]);
    const myComponent = mount(<MyComponent />);
    expect(myComponent.find('Text')).not.toExist();
  });

  test('When Keyboard shows up, set showText to false; when disappear, set showText to true', () => {
    mockKeyboardListener.mockImplementation((event, cb) => {
      keyboardCallbackMap[event] = cb;
    });
    mockUseState.mockImplementation(showText => [showText, mockSetShowText]);
    const myComponent = mount(<MyComponent />);
    keyboardCallbackMap.keyboardDidShow(); // mock keyboardDidShow event
    expect(mockSetShowText).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
    keyboardCallbackMap.keyboardDidHide(); // mock keyboardDidHide event
    expect(mockSetShowText).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
    myComponent.unmount();
  });
});
```